# Necesito sacar variable de while

Tags: php

Tengo el resultado de una consulta lo cual lo muestro en un `while` que la tengo en una variable llamada `$email`, ahora lo que quiero es llevar a esa variable fuera de ese bucle, pero al llevarla no no me muestra su contenido.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $email = $row['email'];
  }
} else {

    

}
echo $email; <++++++++ Es aquí en dónde quiero que lleve y me muestre mi variable
```

Comment: No entiendo porque deseas sacarla fuera del bucle? En el caso que te devuelva mas de un resultado la consulta, te va a mostrar solo el ultimo

Comment: prueba a usar echo var_export($email,true); igual la sql no te devuelve nada y por eso no te muestra nada en pantalla. fetch_assoc() te devuelve un array asociativo estas teniendo eso en cuenta a la hora de imprimir?

Comment: Podrías utilizar un if en lugar de un while

Comment: o creas una función la cual se estará ejecutando dentro del while y dentro de esa función le pasaras como parámetro ese dato que quieres imprimir o metes esos datos dentro de un array u cuando termine de iterar tu array 1 al final de todo imprimes el array que creaste, unicamente se me ocurren esas 2 opciones.

Answer (score 1):

#### Primer paso:

Tienes que hacer un debug de tu código; el primer paso es verificar si esta trayendo la informacion:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $email = $row['email']; //imprime a variable a ver si es que de verdad esta trallendola
  }
}
```

#### Segundo paso:

Ahora todo depende de lo que te haya impreso por pantalla; veras si siempre recibes `1 Registro` entonces esta demás que uses un bucle, esto debería ser suficiente:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $email = $row['email'];
}
echo 'el correo es: ' . $email;
```

Si el Caso es que hay `uno o más registro` entonces tu script quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$email=[];
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $email[] = $row['email'];
}elseif($result->num_rows > 1){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $email[] = $row['email'];
  }
}
// Email separado por coma
echo 'el correo es: ' .PHP_EOL. implode(",", $email);

// Email formato Lista hacia abajo:
echo 'el correo es: ' .PHP_EOL. implode(PHP_EOL, $email);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el `elseif`? Sea una fila, sean mil filas, `$email` se llenará igual con esto simplemente: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $email[] = $row['email'];
  }
}` lo que cambia toda la lógica, si lo piensas bien, es verificar si `num_rows` es mayor que `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo hice logré sacarla de esta manera:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$email [] = $row['email'];

echo $email;

  }

} else {

    

}
//y fuera del bucle
echo '<pre>';
print_r($email);
echo '</pre>';
```

Pero me muestra esto en pantalla:

```
Array
Array
(
[0] => termostato@gmail.com
)
Array
(
[0] => termostato@gmail.com
)
```

Cuando en realidad quiero que muestre esto en la pantalla:

termostato@gmail.com

Comment: eso no funciona así; tienes un error de lógica.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es ese error de lógica?

Comment: Así es como puedo sacar ese valor en pantalla